# How to handle large set of features in Weka?

Tags: java, weka

I want to generate Document-Term Matrix for 2000 documents using Weka. It is giving following error due to having more than 30000 features available in the dataset.

> org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException: Parse error
>   org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException: Parse error
>           org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine.parse(JRIEngine.java:262)
>           org.rosuda.REngine.REngine.parseAndEval(REngine.java:101)
>           org.rosuda.REngine.REngine.parseAndEval(REngine.java:108)
>           weka.core.RSessionImpl.parseAndEval(RSessionImpl.java:699)
>           weka.core.RSession.parseAndEval(RSession.java:361)
>           weka.core.RUtils.instancesToDataFrame(RUtils.java:115)
>         weka.gui.beans.JavaGDConsolePanel.pushInstancesToR(JavaGDConsolePanel.ja
>   va:771)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           weka.gui.explorer.ExplorerRConsolePanel.setInstances(ExplorerRConsolePan
>   el.java:133)
>           weka.gui.explorer.Explorer$1.propertyChange(Explorer.java:261)
>           java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
>           java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
>           java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
>           weka.gui.explorer.PreprocessPanel$14.run(PreprocessPanel.java:535)
>           java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>           java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>           java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>           java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)
>           java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>           java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>           java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>           java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>
> ... ...
>   Selected Use an artificial time index Data too large
>   to calculate PCA. Defaulting to a random projection.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception is due to the RPlugin package for WEKA. If you do not require access to R from WEKA, uninstall that package to avoid this exception.